How can i get Weak Convergence from a set $H$?
I am struggling to understand a Theorem in Measure Theory, Probability, and Stochastic Processes (Jean-François Le Gall) p218.
The Theorem is as follows:

Theorem:Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of independent and
identically distributed random variables with values in $\mathbb{R}^d$.
$\forall \omega \in \Omega$ and every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let
$\mu_{n,\omega}$ be the probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$ defined
by $$\mu_{n,\omega}:=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\delta_{X_i(\omega)}.$$ Then
we have
$$\mu_{n,\omega}\xrightarrow{(\mathrm{w})}_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}_{X_1}\:,\quad
a.s. w\in \Omega$$

Some defination:(1)Let $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^d)$ be the Borel algebra in $\mathbb R^d$ $$A\in \mathcal B(\mathbb R^d),\delta_{X_i(w)}(A):=\mathbf{1}_A(X_j(\omega))$$
(2)$$\mu_{n,\omega}\xrightarrow{(\mathrm{w})}_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}_{X_1}\:,\quad a.s. \omega\in \Omega$$ means $\mu_{n,w}$ converges weakly to $\mathbb P_{X_1}$,i.e.$$\forall \varphi \in C_c(\mathbb R^d),\int \varphi \mathrm{~d}\mu_{n,\omega}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \int\varphi \mathrm{~d}\mathbb P_{X_1}$$Where $C_c(\mathbb R^d)$ denotes the set of all compactly supported continuous function in $\mathbb R^d$
Here is the proof:

Let $H$ a countable dense subset of $C_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and let $\varphi\in H.$ The strong law of large numbers ensures that
$$\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\varphi(X_i)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{\mathrm{a.s.}}\mathbb{E}[\varphi(X_1)].$$
This can be reformulated as
$$\int\varphi\mathrm{~d}\mu_{n,\omega}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{\mathrm{a.s.}}\int\varphi\mathrm{~d}\mathbb{P}_{X_1}.$$
Since $H$ is countable, up to discarding a countable union of sets of probability zero,we get
$$\int\varphi\mathrm{~d}\mu_{n,\omega}\underset{n\to\infty}{\operatorname*{\longrightarrow}}\int\varphi\mathrm{~d}\mathbb{P}_{X_1},\mathrm{~}\forall\varphi
\in H,\mathrm{~a.s.}$$
Since $H$ is dense in $C_c(\mathbb R^d)$,we complete
the
proof.$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\square$

Question:I feel confused about the set $H$,because by The strong law of large numbers we have already got:$$\forall \varphi\in C_c(\mathbb R^d),\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\varphi(X_i)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{\mathrm{}}\mathbb{E}[\varphi(X_1)]=\int\varphi\mathrm{~d}\mathbb{P}_{X_1},a.s. \omega\in \Omega$$And i know that $$\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\varphi(X_i)=\int \varphi \mathrm{~d}\mu_{n,\omega}$$Is it enough to get the Weak Convergence?If so,why should i consider the set $H$?If not,what's the purpose of the set $H$?
Any help would be appreciated.

The subtlety lies in the fact that for each $\varphi\in C_c\left(\mathbb R^d\right)$, the set of probability one where the convergence takes place depends on $\varphi$: we can find $\Omega_\varphi$ of probability one such that for each $\omega\in\Omega_\varphi$, $\int \varphi \mathrm{~d}\mu_{n,\omega}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \int\varphi \mathrm{~d}\mathbb P_{X_1}$. But we want to find a set $\Omega'$ such that for each $\varphi\in C_c\left(\mathbb R^d\right)$ and $\omega\in\Omega'$, $\int \varphi \mathrm{~d}\mu_{n,\omega}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \int\varphi \mathrm{~d}\mathbb P_{X_1}$, that is, a common set. The choice $\Omega'=\bigcap_{\varphi\in C_c\left(\mathbb R^d\right)}\Omega_\varphi$ is not right because the intersection is not countable.
